# validar Rut chileno con vuejs sin necesidad de enviar el formulario

Tags: vue.js

busco como hacer para validar el rut al momento que se este escribiendo sin necesidad de enviar o apretar el enviar formulario para que valide estoy utilizado vue con laravel

Answer (score 1):

hay muchos ejemplos en internet... fijate que hacer la validacion del lado de cliente sin enviar formulario seria que tengas un boton que tenga que en el click llame codigo javascript... nada distinto a cualquier framework sea vuejs, react, angular, etc....

te dejo un ejemplo tomado de internet (con jquery, en vuejs seria llamar a codigo en "methods" como diferencia):
https://codepen.io/donpandix/pen/jWNNKj

```
var Fn = {
    // Valida el rut con su cadena completa "XXXXXXXX-X"
    validaRut : function (rutCompleto) {
        rutCompleto = rutCompleto.replace("‐","-");
        if (!/^[0-9]+[-|‐]{1}[0-9kK]{1}$/.test( rutCompleto ))
            return false;
        var tmp     = rutCompleto.split('-');
        var digv    = tmp[1]; 
        var rut     = tmp[0];
        if ( digv == 'K' ) digv = 'k' ;

        return (Fn.dv(rut) == digv );
    },
    dv : function(T){
        var M=0,S=1;
        for(;T;T=Math.floor(T/10))
            S=(S+T%10*(9-M++%6))%11;
        return S?S-1:'k';
    }
}


$("#btnvalida").click(function(){
    if (Fn.validaRut( $("#txt_rut").val() )){
        $("#msgerror").html("El rut ingresado es válido :D");
    } else {
        $("#msgerror").html("El Rut no es válido :'( ");
    }
});
```

html:

```
<header>
  <h1>Valida RUT</h1>
  <p>Algoritmo de validaciónd del rut Chileno</p>
</header>
  <content>
    <div id="wrapper" >
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">Rut</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rut a validar, ej: 11111111-1" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" id="txt_rut">
      </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <button id="btnvalida" class="btn btn-default">Valida RUT</button>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="text-info" id="msgerror"></p>
    </div>
  </content>
```

para el caso de vuejs deberias usar un boton y textbox bindeado al dato 'rut'

html:

```
<input v-model="rut" placeholder="ingrese rut">
<button v-on:click="validarrut">Validar RUT</button>
```

Ahora bien, y respondiendo a tu pregunta, en el component Vue.JS:

```
  data: {
    rut: ''
  },
  methods: {
    // Valida el rut con su cadena completa "XXXXXXXX-X"
    validaRut: function(rutCompleto) {
    rutCompleto = rutCompleto.replace("‐","-");
    if (!/^[0-9]+[-|‐]{1}[0-9kK]{1}$/.test( rutCompleto ))
        return false;
    var tmp     = rutCompleto.split('-');
    var digv    = tmp[1];
    var rut     = tmp[0];
    if ( digv == 'K' ) digv = 'k' ;

    return (this.dv(rut) == digv );
},
dv : function(T){
    var M=0,S=1;
    for(;T;T=Math.floor(T/10))
        S=(S+T%10*(9-M++%6))%11;
    return S?S-1:'k';
},
```

}

En mi caso, tengo otra function (updateRutNum) que llama a validaRut a través de 
console.log(this.validaRut(this.rut));
y me devuelve un dato boolean.

Si el RUT está correcto es true.
Si es false le puedes colocar un alert('');
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]